# How does the stress vector change with respect to the radial coordinate at the radial surface of a cylinder?

Tags: symmetry, boundary-conditions, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

Consider a linearly elastic vertical cylinder in the gravitational field with its base attached to a rigid wall while its other base is under uniformly distributed time-varying pressure. Its radial surface is free.

[image: Cylinder]

I read in literature that in this system the stress vector on the radial surface of the cylinder is zero:

$$ \vec S(t, r_{max}, z) = 0 \tag1 $$

This means that the stress vector on the radial surface does not change along the $z$ axis:

$$ { {\partial \vec S(t, r, z)} \over {\partial z} } \Bigg |_{r=r_{max} } = 0 \tag3 $$

I did not find this fact in literature, but it makes sense to me. However, the stress vectors value changes along the radial coordinate.

My question is: Is the radial partial derivative of the stress vector at the radial surface also equal to zero?

$$ { {\partial \vec S(t, r, z)} \over {\partial r} } \Bigg |_{r=r_{max} } = 0 \tag 3 $$

If the equation above is not true, is there anything we actually do know about the stress vector's first or second radial partial derivative at the radial boundary?